# Storing html pages containing quotes in SQL

Tags: html, database, rich-text-editor, double-quotes, single-quotes

I would like to store entire HTML pages into a database.

My only problem is that my html page contains both single quotes and double quote. How can i wrap everything into a single string?

Also keep in mind that i want my users to be able to modify the content within a web based text editor ( such as tinymce or ck editor ).

What would be the simplest solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the software you use, the software will contain methods to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

To store HTML pages into a column in a database, you will have to escape the characters. In PHP, that's the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function, might be helpful to look into that.